# Angular 8 PWA application puts Server-Sent events in pending state forever

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, server-sent-events

It seems that only when application is compiled for production (PWA) in Angular 8 causes problems for the browser to receive SSE events from the server.

If I run the application in development mode (simply with `ng serve`) things work as expected. So my initial thought is that PWA is somehow the root of the problem.

I've tried to exclude the caching on the api `/v1/events` in `ngsw-config.json` but there is no difference:

```json
{
    "name":"api",
    "urls": ["/api/v1/**"],
    "cacheConfig": {
      "maxSize": 0,
      "maxAge": "0u",
      "strategy": "freshness"
    }
  }
```

Anyone had a similar problem and managed to solve it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i figured it out. I've simply added a call to my API `/v1/events` a query parameter to bypass the service worker: `/v1/events?ngsw-bypass=true`.

I found the answer on [Angular web page](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#bypassing-the-service-worker)

> In some cases, you may want to bypass the service worker entirely and let the browser handle the request instead. An example is when you rely on a feature that is currently not supported in service workers (e.g. reporting progress on uploaded files). To bypass the service worker you can set ngsw-bypass as a request header, or as a query parameter. (The value of the header or query parameter is ignored and can be empty or omitted.)